# Redirect to external URL with some parameters

Tags: django

I was trying to redirect the user to an external URL(such as https://stockoverflow.com) and that URL contains a login form.
I would like to fill in the username and password column for the user.
As if there's auto-complete function.
I can't figure it out by using redirect or HttpResponseRedirect.
Could someone enlight me or give me some directions?

Comment: This cannot be done, unless the external URL cooperated with you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the email and hashed password via `GET` parameter, then get them in destination URL and parse them into your form. But this approach is not recommended at all.